# Is it possible to edit the formatting of a Microsoft Word document in plain text editors?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

The current situation: I have a full document in Microsoft Word, that I need to change the formatting of some words. For example, I currently have the word `A1` typed out as is, but I need to put them in a formula form and have the `1` in subscript.

Idea: Is there any way I can export the Word document into something like HTML, so that the formatting is tagged in a plain-text file, and I can use a plain-text editor to just replace all `A1` with `<math>A<sub>1</sub></math>` instead of replacing them one by one in Word like I'm currently doing? After that, I can reimport into Word and retain all the current formatting that I do not want changed.

Note: the above example is only one of the example that one could do, if one were to be able to edit a `docx` file's formatting like HTML tags. The question is more general: if a `docx` file can be edited like one could edit HTML files in a plain text editor, formatting and all

Comment: Edit the `docx` file? It is an Open XML Formate Document...

Comment: I think `docx` is a binary file. If I open it in Notepad++ for example, it shows it as if the encoding is wrong, but I can't find the correct encoding. Both the default `docx` and the strict Open XML `docx`.

Comment: If the file is simple enough you may be able to save as .xml format, which is directly editable. The markup  is not as simple as your "example" so it may take time to work out what to change. A .docx is actually a .zip with .xml files internally (and binary files if the document contains binary stuff such as images or objects). You can unzip the file, work with the content, and re-zip, but I'd go through the process and make sure it works on your system.

Comment: Yeah, I forget it is zipped.

Comment: @AnonymousMouse Do you only want to change the subscript? If yes, do your areas that you want to subscript follow any pattern? "Find and Replace" is a powerful tool in Word, so if there is a pattern, let us know and maybe the solution is the "Find and Replace" tool

Comment: @Loeli Not just subscript unfortunately, but for the above example specifically, I found out that if I change one instance of `A1` into a formula form, and copy it, I can use "Find and Replace" to search for all `A1` and replace with `^c`, it'll replace all with what's in my clipboard, and by changing all formula into linear (instead of professional), "Find and Replace" works even within formulas. So with this two workarounds, I could solve the example above.

Comment: @AnonymousMouse got it - I tried editing the XML file in the meantime, but when zipping it back to a docx file, Word tells me that the file is broken. Therefore, I don't think that editing directly in XML is a good option and you are most likely best off with the "Find and Replace" tool

Comment: The intention of the question originally was not specifically for the example above, but more in general, as it seems that it's a no-brainer that the formatting should work like an HTML file with tags. I did not realize that `docx` files are actually zipped Open XML files, and the comments from @DavidPostill and @jonsson joined the dots for me. But also it seems more like a workaround than an "official" way, and after @Loeli's new comment, an unreliable way to batch edit a `docx` file.

Comment: @harrymc It is not necessarily an *unreliable* method so much as a tedious and difficult method compared to using Find and Replace within Word itself as shown in harrymc's answer. This requires much more knowledge of both XML and of Word's document structures than doing this within Word requires.

Comment: @KJ so there's no "lossless" type of conversion I guess, because of proprietary stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler method :

- Use Word to search and replace all `A1` by some unlikely string such
  as `A1@@`
- Search and replace `1@@` by `1`, but do also this in the dialog:

  - Click the button "More >>"
  - Click "Format" and select "Font..."
  - Check "Subscript" and click OK
- Click "Replace All".

---

The DOCX format is an open standard that is documented in the
[OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument)](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office).

A DOCX file a collection of XML files that are contained inside
a ZIP archive. The contents of a Word document can be viewed by
unzipping its contents.

The collection contains a list of XML files that are
categorized as:

- MetaData Files : contain information about other files
  available in the archive,
- Document : contains the actual contents of the document.

For more information, you will need to study the standard.

Comment: While this solves half of the mentioned example, I should've been more clear from the start that the goal of this question is not to solve the example, but more about trying to find out if there is a way that `docx` formatting can be edited like HTML tags in plain text editor

Comment: Yes, you can, but requires a steep learning curve. I added more information about the DOCX format, if you wish to go this way.

Comment: The link you added is indeed a good starting point. However, is `docx` an open standard? The link you gave is for ODF (`odt` files for Word-like documents), `docx` and `odt` are not 1-to-1 compatible, Microsoft themselves said as much [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/differences-between-the-opendocument-text-odt-format-and-the-word-docx-format-d9d51a92-56d1-4794-8b68-5efb57aebfdc)

Comment: Office Open XML (which `docx` file is a part of) is standardized under ISO/IEC 29500, so yes, they are open format, but not the same as ODF.

Answer (score 0):

A DOCX is a ZIP FOLDER containing "TEXT".XML files. (Needs unpack and repack with TAR).
`TAR -m -xf MsWord.docx & cd word & notepad document.xml`

Text CAN be programmatically EDITED IN NOTEPAD. (This requires some registry edits and using a macro language file like Wscript SendKeys)

So the answer is YES, but why, when Word has a much more powerful macro editor and VBA rather than VBS.

[image]

[image]

Repack after edits using TAR beware for save name must be zip then rename.

`Tar -a -cf new.zip [content_Types].xml word\*.* docProps\*.* _rels\*.* & ren new.zip "Hello World A1 whatever.docx"`

[image]